# New research and re-discovering classic results in "basic" real analysis

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, real-analysis, big-list

Sometimes, it happens that researchers publish a new proof of an old well-known result in "basic real analysis" (I'm referring to what some American people may call "honors calculus"). For instance, we can consider [this article](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/4145046?uid=3738296&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104830505661).

I have two questions:

> **(1)** What are some examples recent novel proofs of old well-known results in "basic real analysis"?
>
> **(2)** Has it ever happened in recent times that such a proof
>   had been particularly useful bringing about new
>   insights into major problems?

Comment: My goodness! After reading this post i thought about Lars Olsen who would love this type of things, and the author in the link is him!

Comment: never mind what others vote for. I have a nice example for you! The old method to prove $\pi$ is not algebraic is involved. But there is an elementary half-page proof using $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})\times\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$ and analytic tricks to deal with product of two integrals (argument is going from the contrary)

Comment: @Victor : Perhaps you should post an answer with more details about your nice example.

Comment: I do not favour closing this question. I find the second clause of the question particularly interesting: I would not find it hard to list some examples of novel proofs of classical, elementary results (not necessarily in analysis), but I find it much harder to think of examples such that the new proof has had substantial research consequences. I would be very interested to learn about such examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Google Scholar to search for recent American Mathematical Monthly articles containing the term "new proof" turns up some candidates.  For example, Steve Roman's paper on [The Formula of Faà di Bruno](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2320788) derives the formula using the umbral calculus.  The umbral calculus is a classical technique that has been revived to produce numerous interesting new results; I'm most familiar with applications in combinatorics, as explained in [Ira Gessel's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0108121), but there are probably others.

Comment: This is really interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one I once saved:

- Peter D. Lax, [Change of variables in multiple integrals](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1699248) (1999).

It gave rise to two postscripts:

- Peter D. Lax, [Change of variables in multiple integrals. II](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1818184) (2001),
- Nikolai V. Ivanov, [A differential forms perspective on the Lax proof of the change of variables formula](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2179859) (2005).